# Power Query - Combine all lookup values from both tables and create a single column

Tags: excel, join, powerquery, lookup

Apologies if this has been asked before, although I tried searching on the forum and didn't find anything.

Let's say I have two tables having identical columns. The only difference is that these are for two different dates hence the values might change.

*Table 1: YDAY*

| ID | Name | Dept | Salary | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X02 | Jim | HR | 40,000 | 03/31/2021 |
| X03 | Ray | Admin | 45,000 | 03/31/2021 |
| X04 | Mark | Sales | 55,000 | 03/31/2021 |

*Table 2: YDAY*

| ID | Name | Dept | Salary | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X01 | John | Sales | 50,000 | 03/31/2020 |
| X02 | Jim | HR | 40,000 | 03/31/2020 |
| X03 | Ray | Admin | 45,000 | 03/31/2020 |

Now I use Power Query merge request and select ID as the lookup value and perform an outerjoin (i.e. pick up all the ids). However when I do that it will keep two lookup columns separately. What I want to do is merge both of them and create a unified column for ID, which contains all of the IDs in both data sets (i.e. X01 which was present in YDAY but not today and X04 which was present in TODAY but not YDAY). See below for desired result.
Can you please help or point out in the right direction?

My desired result is as follows.

| ID | Name | Dept | Salary | Date | Name_Prev | Dept_Prev | Salary_Prev | Date_Prev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X01 |  |  |  |  | John | Sales | 50,000 | 03/31/2020 |
| X02 | Jim | HR | 40,000 | 06/30/2021 | Jim | HR | 40,000 | 03/31/2020 |
| X03 | Ray | Admin | 45,000 | 06/30/2021 | Ray | Admin | 45,000 | 03/31/2020 |
| X04 | Mark | Sales | 55,000 | 06/30/2021 |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Just add a calculated column, then remove the two original columns?

Comment: @Rory That's what I was worried about. No other way? The thing is I have 100+ columns and might need to lookup on 20+ of these at different instances. So just wanted to check if there was an automatic way out.
Thanks BTW.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a consolidated list of IDs from both tables as a separate query, and then merge it with Table1 and Table2 to get your desired output. Not sure if it would be any more efficient but it's an option.

```
let
  #"Table1 IDs" = Table.SelectColumns(Table1,{"ID"}),
  #"Table2 IDs" = Table.SelectColumns(Table2,{"ID"}),
  #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Table1 IDs", #"Table2 IDs"}),
  #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Appended Query"),
  #"Merge with Table1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Duplicates", {"ID"}, Table1, {"ID"}, "Table1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
  #"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merge with Table1", "Table1", {"Name", "Dept", "Salary", "Date"}, {"Name", "Dept", "Salary", "Date"}),
  #"Merge with Table2" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Table1", {"ID"}, Table2, {"ID"}, "Prev", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
  #"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merge with Table2", "Prev", {"Name", "Dept", "Salary", "Date"}, {"Prev.Name", "Prev.Dept", "Prev.Salary", "Prev.Date"}),
  #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Table2",{{"ID", Order.Ascending}})
in
  #"Sorted Rows"
```